# Maven Parallel Build Sequence some modules

Tags: maven

Multiple modules, the last package module requires the last compilation, how to do?
How do you control the sequence?

Comment: The order of build in a multi module build is defined by the dependencies. If a module needs another module you have to define a dependency to it. This will change the order. You don't control it yourself. Only via dependencies.

Comment: Regarding the awesome links. They are reference links. They are defined at the bottom like this: `[OSS Icon]: https://jaywcjlove.github.io/sb/ico/min-oss.svg "Open Source Software"`.